# What are some sites with excellent UI design when displaying lists and checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a good example of lists and checkboxes design.  I have to build an app where there will be lists and checkboxes to select items etc...a site with just lists can get a little boring, so wouldn't mind getting some inspiration.

Please let me know of any sites that you think have good UI design when it comes to displaying lists and checkboxes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Some cool list styles...](http://www.marcofolio.net/css/8_different_ways_to_beautifully_style_your_lists.html)

[Several options for checkboxes and forms here...](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/08/25/how-to-use-pure-css-to-style-web-form-dynamically-plus-12-awesome-javascript-plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

http://svpply.com/ on the right has a clean checkboxes. The whole site is minimally designed too.